# Deploy a java web service on glashfish manually

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish

I created a web service in `netbeans` an deploy it on `glassfish 3` using netbeans. Everything going right , an I use that web service on a client application and call its methods. Now I want to install the web service on an other machine. I installed `JDK SDK` and also `GlassFish SDK` on that new machine , Now what can I do to deploy web service on that machine ? I do not want install `netbean` on it, Is there anyway to deploy the web service on that machine using command line ? Is there any thing else that I should install on that machine ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just start the glashfish server using the following command :

```
asadmin start-domain --verbose
```

[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadi.html) is a detailed tutorial.

Now login as server admin: The default administration server’s port number is 4848.

```
example - localhost:4848/
```

The default user name is admin, and by default no password is required and deploy the application form the GUI there.

[here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1757/geyvr/) is a detailed tutorial on how to deploy and app on glashfish.

Comment: Thanks for the second given link. One of the best thing I saw on that page was AutoDeploy . I easy copy the WAR file into a folder an it deloys itself :) .as easy as possible . So thanks again